# Using $elemMatch in projection field - not filtering as desired

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This schema:

```
var Order = new Schema({
  name: String,
  products: [{
    product: {
     type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "Product"
    },
    qty: Number
  }]
 });
```

I would like to find and return the order with only the product that has the matching id.  My attempt at $elemMatch have not been successful and seem to return the entire order with all products. I can use the position operator ($) but would like in this case to specifically use $elemMatch.

Note that each product in the order is unique (within that order)

This returns all products:

```
Order.find({ _id: req.params.id}, { 'products.product': {$elemMatch: { _id: req.params.product }}}, function(err, order) {
```

This returns empty:

```
Order.find({ _id: req.params.id}, { 'products': {$elemMatch: { 'product._id': req.params.product }}}, function(err, order) {
```

What is correct syntax?  I would like the order returned with just one (matching) product.

Comment: It may be #code Order.find({ _id: req.params.id,'products.product._id': req.params.product}, { 'products.$' : 1}}}, function(err, order) { #code. But it only retrieve maximum one (the first found) product in the products array. If one Order contains more than one same products, it will only return one. The only way to do this is by using aggregation. Use $unwind operation in the aggregation, followed by $match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `products` array, the `product` field directly contains the product's id, so the correct syntax would be:

```
Order.find(
    { _id: req.params.id}, 
    { products: {$elemMatch: { product: req.params.product }}}, 
    function(err, order) { ... });
```

Comment: This returns pretty much nothing. Here's what it returned: `[ { _id: 007d0000b10000000000000c, products: [] } ]`

Comment: Actually hold on... I have 2 ids for every product - the one for 'product' and the one that Mongo assigns to the objects under products - I may have them mixed up

Answer (score 0):

You can use query projection only, if the product in an order is always unique (there can't be more than 1 same product in 1 order). If same product can appear more than one in 1 order, you cannot use query projection since it will only return the first found product in products array.

Instead, use aggregation. Make use of $unwind and $match operator.
It will be something like this in mongo shell javascript.

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    {$match: {_id: Order_id_being_search}},
    {$unwind: "$products"}, 
    {$match: {"products.product._id": Product_id_being_search }}
])
```

It will return the desired product (only the product), in a selected Order document. If you want to return the desired product from all Order, just omit the first $match.

Sorry, I am not used to using "REF" so I assume a manual reference using _id key on the code above. You can modify that part in the code. You can use the algo.

MongoDB uses aggregation not only to find aggregation value like sum, avg, max, etc, like relational ones. It also uses aggregation framework for dealing with subdocuments. Your case is a perfect example of the use case of $unwind operation in aggregation framework.

Comment: I have rephrased my question a bit - I do want to return the order but I want only one product in the order. I believe that $elemMatch is all I need according to docs but..

Comment: Okay my bad. I am sorry that I led you to wrong direction. Happy that you already got the answer for it..